# Calculate total area height and width from various BoxCollider2Ds

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math

I have a a BoxCollider2D on different child gameobjects that live in a single parent gameobject.

[image]

I need to know the total *height* and *total* width **of the area** of the box colliders.

During **Start()**, I loop through every child component, read the box collider size and add it to a `Vector2` property called `totalSize`.

```
private Vector2 totalSize;

foreach (Transform child in transform)
{
    var col = child.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
    if(col != null)
        totalSize += new Vector2(col.bounds.size.x, col.bounds.size.y);
}
```

However, this calculates ALL objects giving me 220 x 100 instead of giving me 100 x 50 for the pictured example. Where each grey box represents a BoxCollider2D.

How do I find the true area height and width given that each "box" can be different sizes or in a different configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this. It should find the total size of the bounds of all the children together.

```
private Vector2 totalSize;

private float minX = Mathf.Infinity;
private float maxX = -Mathf.Infinity;
private float minY = Mathf.Infinity;
private float maxY = -Mathf.Infinity;

foreach (Transform child in transform)
{
    var col = child.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
    if(col != null){
        if(col.bounds.max.x > maxX) maxX = col.bounds.max.x;
        if(col.bounds.min.x < minX) minX = col.bounds.min.x;

        if(col.bounds.max.y > maxY) maxY = col.bounds.max.y;
        if(col.bounds.min.y < minY) minY = col.bounds.min.y;
    }
}
totalSize = new Vector2(maxX-minX, maxY-minY);
```

Comment: Don't feel like you need to edit this in also, but I would like to add that another way to do the `if (abc<xyz) xyz = abc;` type lines is to do `xyz = Mathf.Min(abc,xyz);`

Comment: starting with any of the `BoxCollider2D.Bounds` one could also use `Bounds.Encapsulate(Bounds)` https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Bounds.Encapsulate.html